# Rolling up line items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a case where an order has a header which is a summary of an order (without price details) then I have a order line detail view as well. So the hearder shows and overview, while the line detail will list each item and its price, one per line. What id like to do is provide a header-like view with the line item prices rolled up. for instance the line will show

```
Line Num    Price
1           450.00
2           100.00
3           100.00
```

So what id like to do is roll the prices into one value of 650.00 in my query. heres what I'm trying, but its showing each line item instead of a sum of all prices.:

```
Select
PURCHLINE.PURCHID, 
SUM(Purchline.PurchPrice)
FROM PURCHLINE
INNER JOIN PURCHTABLE ON PURCHTABLE.PURCHID= PURCHLINE.PURCHID 
where PURCHLINE.PURCHID ='192325'
group by PURCHLINE.PURCHID, 
PURCHNAME,
PurchPlacer,
PURCHTABLE.createdDate,
PURCHLINE.REMAINPURCHPHYSICAL
```

PURCHTABLE is the header table while PURCHLINE is the line item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to group by too many fields. In general, you only group by the fields that appear in the `SELECT` list.

To your question: use `ROLLUP`

```
Select
PURCHLINE.PURCHID, 
SUM(Purchline.PurchPrice)
FROM PURCHLINE
INNER JOIN PURCHTABLE ON PURCHTABLE.PURCHID= PURCHLINE.PURCHID 
where PURCHLINE.PURCHID ='192325'
group by PURCHLINE.PURCHID WITH ROLLUP
```

**Edit:** the OP indicates he's using SQL Server 2005. For that, use `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`. Note that `WITH ROLLUP` is marked as obsolete by Microsoft and will likely be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Here's the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms177673(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: Im using 2005, and Rollup doesnt seem to be an option

Comment: I updated my question to address SQL Server 2005. Don't have a 2005 boxing sitting here so I'm just going by the documentation. Please include the software version for you future questions.

Comment: This gives me an odd result showing the original results plus one total for each item in the Group by clause (I simplified my query for illustration. I have five items to group by, so I get 5 items underneath the original line items.)

Comment: Which table does your `Line Num` come from? Or is it simply a sequence from 1 - n assigned at random?

Comment: The line number comes from the PURCHTABLE. Each line item is assigned a sequential line number. the PURCHID ='192325' is the headers overall purchase order. So i am selecting order '192325' and it is displaying three line items as demonstrated in the question. I need information from both the header (PURCHTABLE) and Line item (PURCHLINE) tables.

Comment: i am tring a subquery:  (select SUM(Purchline.LINEAMOUNT) 
  from PURCHLINE 
  where PURCHLINE.PURCHID ='192325'
  group by PurchPrice WITH ROLLUP)
This returns three results. the end result is the correct total. But i cant get at it because MAX is not allowed

Comment: I think the easiest to resolve this is to post your table schema with some sample data. Can you edit your question?